# c# assign multiple values taken from a single text box to labels

Tags: c#, split

I want to input more than 1 number to a text box separated by commas and display each number in a label.
My problem is how to set the delimiter as comma and what method should I use to get all the numbers from a single text box?

Comment: it it so, use `Split()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Split, you can do the following:

```
List<int> numbersFromInput = txtBoxInput.Text.Split(',')
                                        .Where(x=> x.All(c => Char.IsNumber(c)))
                                        .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x))
                                        .ToList();
```

For info, you can combine a list to a single string with a delimeter using the below code:

```
txtBoxInput.Text = String.Join(",", numbersFromInput);
```

Comment: How can I get the values from the text box to the numbers List. I'm a complete beginner

Comment: @niki123 This is exactly the last part of the code above.

Comment: @user3185569 - I think it would be nice if you reversed the order of your code and made it clear on the flow. I was a bit confused why you had the `List<int>` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to solve my own problem :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
            String numbers = textBox1.Text;
            String[] numbersArray = numbers.Split(delimiterChars);
            int[] num = Array.ConvertAll(numbersArray,Convert.ToInt32);
           // MessageBox.Show("No1 :"+num[0].ToString());

        }
```